# Javascript photos advance too far

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, gallery

I am trying to cycle through photos in an array with "previous" and "next" links/buttons. I have been doing fine on my site with `html` and `css`, but the `JavaScript` is really throwing me for a loop.

I'm learning still so if anyone could help out, that would be great. The idea is to be able to add an indefinite number of photos to the gallery. The code I have so far is below, but it doesn't seem to be working. I am trying to get it so clicking the "**next**" button on the last image will take me back to the first, and the "**previous**" button on the first image will take me to the last.

```js
    var counter = 0;
    var srcArray = ["photos/0.jpg", "photos/1.jpg", "photos/2.jpg"];
    
    prev.onclick = function()
    {
        document.getElementById("currentImage").src = srcArray[--counter];
    }
    next.onclick = function()
    {
        document.getElementById("currentImage").src = srcArray[++counter];
    }
    if(counter <= 0)
    {
        counter = 2;
        document.getElementById("currentImage").src = "photos/2.jpg"
    }
    else if(counter >= 2)
    {
        counter = 0;
        document.getElementById("currentImage").src = "photos/0.jpg"
    };
```

```html
<img src= "photos/0.jpg" id="currentImage"  height="288"/>
<p> 
  <button id= "prev" class="portfolioNavigation">Previous</button>
  <button id= "next" class="portfolioNavigation">Next</button>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the modulo operator `%` to keep the arithmetic simple.

```
var index = 0;
var photos = ["photos/0.jpg", "photos/1.jpg", "photos/2.jpg"]
next.onclick = function () {
    load_photo(1);
}
prev.onclick = function () {
    load_photo(-1);
}
function load_photo(offset) {
    index = (index + offset + photos.length) % photos.length;
    document.getElementById("currentImage").src = photos[index];
}
```

There is an extra `+ photos.length` because `%` doesn't convert the negative number to a positive. If `index` is `0` and `offset` is `-1` you want the result to be `2`. `(0 - 1 + 3) % 3` gives `2`.